# New DS 160 barcode generated - will the old one be invalid?

Tags: usa, f1-visas

I wanted to make a small change to my DS-160 form, so I retrieved it and hit the "create new application" button, which generated a new DS-160 barcode. However after I read the following:

> Please note that if you have made your appointment with an invalid or
>   previously used barcode, you must update your profile at least three
>   working days prior to your appointment date with the valid/new and
>   electronically submitted one and print out a new Appointment
>   Confirmation. If you fail to update it three working days prior to
>   your appointment date, you will not be allowed to come for an
>   interview and will need to make a new appointment using a valid DS-160
>   barcode. Please bring the printouts of your DS-160 Confirmation and
>   Appointment Confirmation to your interview.

Since my appointment date is tomorrow, I decided not to follow through with the new form. My old form still seems to be working (I can still retrieve it and everything), but now I'm worried that it might have been rendered invalid because a new barcode is generated.

Should I still go ahead with the appointment or should I make a new one? I'm actually on a very tight timeline due to having a short holiday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new application and receiving a new barcode doesn't invalidate the previous application barcode, but that application won't have the changes you made. If I were you I would just go to the appointment, and inform the consular officer of whatever the change is.